# How to get media bitrate with Libvlc

Tags: libvlc

I'm using libvlc to play video files while downloading them. My problem is that libvlc_media_player_get_length returns nothing.
Also I thought about calculating an approximation using the bitrate and the file size, but I don't find how to get the bitrate with libvlc.

Is there a function for that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I finaly find this way:

```
libvlc_media_stats_t stats;
if (libvlc_media_get_stats(vlcmedia, &stats))
{
    long p=libvlc_media_player_get_time(vlcmediaplayer);

    if (p)
        bitrate=stats.i_read_bytes/p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`libvlc_media_tracks_get` returns one or more structures containing track information.

If the track type is audio or video there is `libvlc_audio_track_t.i_bitrate` or `libvlc_video_track_t.i_bitrate` accordingly.

This API was added at version 2.1.0 of LibVLC, see http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=commit;h=cd5345a00009f2fc571c23509a025331ad24fc87.

VLC 2.1.0 was released in September 2013.

Comment: I don't seem to have libvlc_media_tracks_get ??

Comment: http://git.videolan.org/?p=vlc.git;a=blob;f=include/vlc/libvlc_media.h;h=262a9368b2e033f7264f89e0b07609773ce0925b;hb=HEAD

Comment: In the version of vlc I use it seems to be call libvlc_media_get_tracks_info, is it an older version ?